# Unable to flag or vote on comments on moderator nominations

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, comment-flags, nominations

I find myself unable to vote on comments or flag them for moderator attention in the [current election on Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3).

However, there are some comments that need upvoting (and one that needs flagging, too). Could this be fixed, please?

Others don't seem to have this problem, as there are some upvoted comments on the current nominations. FWIW, I get this error in the JavaScript console:

> getQuestionId could not find an id

(occurs with both Firefox 9.0.1 and a virtually untouched but up-to-date Chrome installation)

Comment: I have similar problems in the Ask Ubuntu elections which I have reported in http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2420/cannot-edit-comments-to-nominees-in-the-election and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2421/posted-comments-to-nominees-also-appears-in-text-area-for-entering-comments

Comment: ***Jarrod!!!***

Comment: [This was also reported on Gaming and was supposed to be fixed now](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3856/comments-on-nominations-and-other-things-appear-to-be-broken/), though I'm also experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed, which is why you see others have voted on comments.  However...

The Amsterdam CDN node is having some issues and serving an older version of the file (ie, pre-bug-fix).  We've contacted their support and hope this resolves soon.

(You can tell if you're hitting Amsterdam by [clicking here](http://debug-02.netdna-cdn.com/)