# Reintroduce flagging of comments on nominations

Tags: feature-request, election, comment-flags, nominations

As seen by the following meta discussions, there is no voting for or flagging of comments on an election nomination:

- [Unable to flag or vote on comments on moderator nominations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120839/unable-to-flag-or-vote-on-comments-on-moderator-nominations)
- [I can't upvote comments to nominations in the Ask Ubuntu Election!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120777/i-cant-upvote-comments-to-nominations-in-the-ask-ubuntu-election)

There have been situations where flagging of comments was warranted on an election nomination, as they detracted from the main focus of the nomination. I agree that the upvoting of comments could be an influence, but there needs to be a way for general users to alert that there are comments that are not serving their intended purpose, or are outright violating policies such as Be Nice.

Can the ability to flag (not upvote) be reinstated on nomination post comments?

Comment: Unfortunately, flagging election comments was removed because it was straight up broken. We could probably restore upvotes with relative ease at this point (I *think* the blocker there has changed in the recent years, though don't quote me on it), but making flagging work would be more of an actual project. I'm not saying we shouldn't do it; only noting that it's more in the "implement" rather than "reinstate" category.