# Where did the "Spam" and "Rude" flags go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, spam, flag-dialog

The 'Red Flags' (Spam and R/A) have disappeared as options in the Flag pop-up for both answers and questions (see below). Where did they go?

[image]

Comment: Those flags were unwelcome ...

Comment: Maybe they noticed that it's time 2 March.

Comment: Note that, for those who really want to continue red-flagging, the [Advanced Flagging](https://github.com/SOBotics/AdvancedFlagging) userscript still seems to offer the ability to do so.

Comment: @AdrianMole No, it does not work (I tested on a sandbox post): http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGkly.png

Comment: Saved, my red flags are back...

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention- just pushed out a fix. I had added flagging to election nominations and accidentally included a bad check. Should be better now!

Comment: @JaneWillborn not on SO.

Comment: It will take a minute to build out to SO, but it's on the way

Comment: @Yatin Deployment of fixes like this typically hits MSE first, then the other sites. I imagine it'll be network-wide soon.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Adding this as an answer for visibility: thanks for bringing this to my attention- just pushed out a fix. I had added flagging to election nominations and accidentally included a bad check. This should be built out network wide now.

Comment: "*I had added flagging to election nominations*" - is that recorded anywhere else on meta? There's a [feature request for allowing election comments to be flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310291/278659), but I'm guessing you mean flagging nominations themselves, which I can't find a previous FR for.

Comment: This is part of a whole bunch of work being done around elections automation and upgrades. Meta post is coming soon.